# FontFamily in music21 lyrics

Tags: python, music21

Is it possible to change the FontFamily of the lyrics of a note or a chord?

I've tried `style.fontFamily` on `Lyric` but no success.

With `TextBox` class I can change the fontFamily. But I cannot tell music21 to display the `TextBox` aligned with the note or chord.

I've created a "pianofont" that I would like to use to display chords (see image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, it's not part of the current music21 specification.

Comment: Is it at least possible to globally change the font used?